# Compute the mode of a list

Tags: haskell

Now I am going to compute the most common item in a list.
I did it step by step.

1. sort the list
2. group the list
3. count how many times of every number
4. I don't know how to continue...please help. This is the code I have
   done now

---

```
group                   :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group                   =  groupBy (==)

-- | The 'groupBy' function is the non-overloaded version of 'group'.
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs  


task4 xs = (map (\l@(x:xs) -> (x,length l)) (group (sortList xs)))    
<main> task4 [1,1,1,2,2,3]
       [(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)]
```

Comment: Are you aware this isn't an efficient method?  The fast method is to keep a mapping of values to counters.  For each value you then lookup and increment each counter value.  Of coarse, this requires a Hashable, Ord or some other helper constraint.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Not efficient in what sense? It's O(n log n) time (the sorting step; everything after that is linear time).

Comment: Do you think that sort is n lg n?

Comment: Oh right, it isn't insertion sort, just an inefficient merge.  NM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  If instead of:

```
(\l@(x:xs) -> (x,length l))
```

you wrote:

```
(\l@(x:xs) -> (length l,x))
```

then you could simply take `maximum` of your output:

```
maximum [(3,1),(2,2),(1,3)] == (3,1)
```

Comment: Ah... Yes. You are right. This is about thinking. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Let's first assume you're only interested in *how often the mode turns up*. So you'd just use

```
   map length . group $ sortList xs
```

giving you a list of lengths of the individual groups. Then what's left to do is retrieve the [`maximum`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=maximum).

Now, that's not all you want. Basically, you want the maximum of your tuple list, but it should compare only the length field, not the element one. You might thus be temped to [hoogle for `Ord b => [(a, b)] -> a`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Ord+b+%3D%3E+%5b%28a%2C+b%29%5d+-%3E+a) (or `-> (a,b)`), but there is no such standard function.

However, as you've already searched for maximum and a special form of this is just what you want, you can scroll down that result page, and you'll find `maximumBy`. It allows you to specify which "property" should be considered for comparison.

The preferred way to use this is the rather self-explanatory

> GHCi> :m +Data.Ord Data.List
>   
> GHCi> :t maximumBy (comparing snd)
>   
> maximumBy (comparing snd) :: Ord a => [(a1, a)] -> (a1, a)

So we're handling the information of how to access the crucial field as an argument to the function. Well, but as `snd` is itself a function, we can as well use any other one! So there's no real need to build up the elem+runlength tuples in the first place, you might as well just do

```
     maximumBy (comparing length) . group $ sort xs
```

which gives the proper result (though that's a bit less efficient). In short:

```
mode :: Ord a => [a] -> a
mode = maximumBy (comparing length) . group . sort
```